# Recognizing extended class object

Tags: java

In Java, I have a class `Num`, and a few classes that extend `Num`, like `Num_int` and `Num_double`.
I want to know whether it's possible for a method to recognize whether a given `Num` object is a `Num_int` or not.

I have the following code:

```
void test(Num_int x) {
  System.out.println("int");
} // test
void test(Num x) {
  System.out.println("other");
} // test

Num_int A = new Num_int( );
Num B     = new Num_int( );
Num C     = new Num_double( );

test(A); // prints "int"
test(B); // prints "other"
test(C); // prints "other"
```

Unfortunately, the method "test" only prints "int" when A is given as argument.
I wan't the function to also print "int" when B is passed, since B is created via `Num B = new Num_int( );`. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: And why do you want to do this?

Comment: The problem is that each extended class must have this method defined for different arguments (other extended classes). In reality it's about the method "Add(Num x)". For class Num_int, I wan't different methods for each class to add, so a method (in Num_int) like Add(Num_int), Add(Num_double), for adding an int to an int and a double to an int, respectively.

Comment: I'm not going to touch the dependency nightmare you are creating. But assuming you have a limited scope for such ... inter-dependencies (aka, limited number of subclasses that are all aware of each other), then you can remove one headache by using more specific names - like `addInt()`, `addDouble` etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x instanceof Num_int) {
  System.out.println("int");
} else {
  System.out.println("other");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want polymorphic behaviour, then make the test method an overridable method of the Num class.

Overloaded methods are not resolved polymorphically based on the runtime type of the arguments. They're resolved at compile-time, based on the declared type of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the `instanceof` operator and casting. However, this is a poor programming practice.

A better option is to make `test()` a non-`final` member of `Num`, and override it appropriately in each class. Then you just call `A.test()`, and Java's dynamic dispatch will take care of everything for you.

```
public class Num {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("other");
  }
}

public class Num_int extends Num {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("int");
  }
}

public class Num_double extends Num {
  // inhertis Num.test()
}
```

Comment: The problem is that each extended class must have this method defined for different classes. In reality it's about the method "Add(Num x)". For class Num_int, I wan't different methods for each class to add, so a method (in Num_int) like Add(Num_int), Add(Num_double), for adding an int to an int and a double to an int, respectively.

Comment: Btw, why is using instanceof a 'poor programming practice'? Is it unstable or something? Or inefficient?

Comment: @MacHans: Not `instanceof` per se, but using `instanceof` to branch depending on object class. The main problem is maintainability: once you add a new class, you have to manually locate all places on your code where you need to add new `else if` clauses for those `instanceof` checks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that method signatures are binded at compile time in Java, so the declared type determines which method is called.

See also the puzzler "Making a Hash of It" in the book [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

You could use double-dispatching and the Visitor pattern. It would look something like this:

```
Num_int A = new Num_int( );
Num B     = new Num_int( );
Num C     = new Num_double( );

Num_printer p = new Num_printer();

A.accept(p);
B.accept(p);
C.accept(p);
```

The `Num_int.accept(...)` and `Num_double.accept(...)` methods would both look like this:

```
public class Num_int extends Num {
    public void accept(Num_visitor v) {
        v.visit(this); // from this scope, `this` has a declared type of `Num_int`
                       // so at compile time this is binded to signature visit(Num_double)
    }
}

public class Num_double extends Num {
    public void accept(Num_visitor v) {
        v.visit(this); // from this scope, `this` has a declared type of `Num_double`
                       // so at compile time this is binded to signature visit(Num_double)
    }
}
```

Even though these methods are almost identical, it's important that the method isn't extracted into the parent class. I'd go so far as to make it abstract in the parent class:

```
public class Num {
    public abstract void accept(Num_visitor);
}
```

From within class `Num`, `this` is of declared type `Num`. If the `accept` method were defined here, the compile-time binding would be to signature `visit(Num)` - giving you the same original problem all over again.

Lastly, the `Num_printer` would look like this:

```
public class Num_printer implements Num_visitor {

    public void visit(Num_int n) {
        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public void visit(Num_double n) {
        System.out.println("double");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm gonna look in to that now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator. Read the "*The Type Comparison Operator instanceof*" part in [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

```
if (x instanceof Num_int) {
  // do something
} else if (x instanceof Num_double) {
  // do something else
}
```